# Method for sensing fault currents with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, current-sensing

How do I choose a proper approach for detecting ground fault currents (20 mA through 30A, 60Hz)? Let's say I have a zero sequence CT and calculate a burden resistor. I have a 12-bit ADC in the micro. I have seen different methods:

1. A peak detector, like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68970/how-is-this-ground-fault-circuit-working)
2. DC biasing [like this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313460/need-help-dc-biasing-an-ac-source)
3. Doing some FFT in the micro?

I want to avoid as much hardware as I can and leverage the microcontroller, even for filtering. Also, I don't think a fixed gain amplifier or burden resistor would cover this wide range of current with good resolution?

I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Use a GFCI (USA) or an RCD (UK)?

Answer (score -1):

I dont have reputation so i could not able to comment.
The most common way is using fuse.But the circuit stops working if fuse breakes .

Do you want to detect the false currents ? or do you want to detect and eliminate or suppress?

For ac circuits you can use bypass capacitors , it short circuits during high frequency.